# How to cache incoming data and periodically send the data to server in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, operating-system, locking

In my code there is an event that carries 3 integers inside its `EventArgs`. What I used to do was to hook up the `EventHandler` and send back the 3 integers to server immediately. Now I'd like to cache the data(3 integers) and send back the sums. The logic is that if in the recent 10 seconds there is no data coming in, send the data. I have two questions about it:

1. Is the code I have (below) suitable for what I want to achieve?
2. I'd like to add some starve-preventing code. Say if there is constantly data coming in then the cached data will never get sent. Maybe adding another timer to force send data every 2 minutes. I'm having trouble figuring out the lock/race condition/critical section stuff. Could anyone point me out what is the best way to achieve this? Thanks!
   The preliminary code I have is like this:

   ```
   public class DataHelper
   {
       private Timer recurringTimer;
       private object resourceLock = new object()
       private ServerConnector connector;
       private Data data;

   public DataHelper(ServerConnector connector)
   {
       this.connector = connector;    
       this.recurringTimer = new Timer(10000);
   }

   public RecordDataEvent(int fallbacks, int total, int failures)
   {
       lock(this.resourceLock)
       {
           if(this.data == null)
           {
               this.data = new Data();
           }
           this.data.fallbacks += fallbacks;
           this.total += total;
           this.failures += failures;    
           //reset the timer
           this.timer.Stop();
           this.timer.Start();
       }
   }

   private void ReportData(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       lock(this.resourceLock)
       {
           if(this.data != null)
           {
               this.connector.ReportData(this.data);
               this.data = new Data();    
           }            
       }    
   }
   }

   class Data
   {
       int fallbacks{get;set;}
       int total{get;set;}
       int failures{get;set;}    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in for some new experience I'd say use reactive extensions for this. See http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html and http://reactivex.io/tutorials.html

Why? Because this framework excels in combining the notion of time with events.

It has the .Buffer operator that does what you need. It buffers until a given threshold is reached or when a given timespan has elapsed, whatever comes first. Also it could throttle events so only after an idle time it will produces items.

See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html

It does need some to learn, but at least google it and give it a try as it will simplify your code a lot!

An example:

```
void Main()
{
    var generator = new EventGenerator();

    // buffer until the event is called 100 times or when a minute has passed, whatever comes first
    var subscription = Observable.FromEventPattern<MyEventArgs>(
        h => generator.MyEvent += h,
        h => generator.MyEvent -= h)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), 100)  
    .Subscribe(e => {}); // do something with the data

    // other code
    while(true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        generator.RaiseEvent(++count);
    }
    // call subscription.Dispose when the eventhandler is no longer needed
}

class EventGenerator
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent(object data)
    {
        if(MyEvent != null)
            MyEvent(this, new MyEventArgs());
    }
}

class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Fallbacks {get;set;}
    public int Total {get;set;}
    public int Failures {get;set;}    
}
```

Note: this code is taken from LinqPad and is not optimized for anything other dan trying things out in LinqPad (http://www.linqpad.net/)